# How do I get Swagger+Swashbuckle to show endpoints?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am trying to add swagger+swashbuckle to my ASP.NET Core project. I can get the Swagger UI up and running but it is completely empty. I tried poking around and found a similar problem at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/1058. This made me think that maybe the routing was the issue so I tried giving my controller an explicit route using `[Route("testroute")]` over the method but not the class. This made the endpoints I added a route to show up with no problem.

As adding an explicit route to every endpoint is non-optimal, what am I doing wrong and how do I fix it to get swagger to show all my endpoints?

My startup where swagger is integrated

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true , reloadOnChange: true);

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

        // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services.AddDbContext<PromotionContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Jasmine"]));
        services.AddTransient<PromotionDbInitializer>();
        services.AddTransient<IComponentHelper, ComponentHelper>();
        services.AddTransient<IComponentFileHelper, ComponentFileHelper>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, PromotionDbInitializer promotionSeeder)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });



        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Promotion}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

       //Because there is not a seed method built into the EF migrations pipeline in EFCore this seeding method will interfere with the migrations when attempting to deploy the database
       //uncomment if you need to seed

       //promotionSeeder.Seed().Wait();
    }
}
```

My controller where the GetAll and Post method show up on the swagger ui page under testroute and testFormRoute, but the Get and Delete methods do not show up

```
public class PromotionController : Controller
{
    private PromotionContext context;
    public PromotionController(PromotionContext _context)
    {
        context = _context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("testroute")]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = context.Promotions
                            .Include(promotion => promotion.CombinabilityType)
                            .Include(promotion => promotion.ValueType)
                            .Include(promotion => promotion.Currency)
                            .Include(promotion => promotion.Components)
                                .ThenInclude(component => component.TargetType)
                            .ToList();
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }


    public IActionResult Get(string promoCode)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = context.Promotions
                                .Include(promotion => promotion.CombinabilityType)
                                .Include(promotion => promotion.ValueType)
                                .Include(promotion => promotion.Currency)
                                .Include(promotion => promotion.Components)
                                    .ThenInclude(component => component.TargetType)
                                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PromoCode == promoCode);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("testFormRoute")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromForm] Promotion newPromotion)
    {
        try
        {
            context.Promotions.Add(newPromotion);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public IActionResult Delete(string promoCode)
    {
        try
        {
            var promotion = context.Promotions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PromoCode == promoCode);

            if(promotion != null)
            {
                context.Promotions.Remove(promotion);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch(DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a route attribute to your controller:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class PromotionController : Controller
{
...
```

And set the HttpGet attribute on your actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
...

[HttpGet("{promoCode}")]
public IActionResult Get(string promoCode)
{
...
```

You have to be careful about how you mix and match static and dynamic routes. Check out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing) for more detail about attribute based routing in asp.net core.

Comment: That worked. I read through the article and I am not seeing why it worked however. As far as I can tell this moves the route I set in the startup to be in the attributes of the class and methods. Do you know why swashbuckle/swagger cannot handle the default routing?

Comment: I'm actually not sure if Swashbuckle properly handles just the default MVC routing for generating documentation. I tend to use attribute routing combined with XML documentation to generate my swagger ui.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
public class PromotionController : Controller
```

to

```
public class PromotionController : ApiController
```

Comment: This is ASP.NET Core so there is no ApiController anymore, the mvc and webapi libraries have been merged and there is only the Controller class